# Android layout_weight getHeight() not accurate

Tags: android

I have defined a set of LinearLayout in xml file, each with an associated layout_weight

This is part of the xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.26"
    android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
```

In total, I have 7 such LinearLayout inside the parent LinearLayout, each with an assign layout_weight. All the layout_weight value add to exactly 1.

Hence, I am expecting the above layout to contains 26% of the total screen height.

However upon calculation:

```
 final LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

    container.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e("mytag", "container Height: " + container.getHeight());
        }
    });
```

container.getHeight() only returns me the value 474, whereas my screen height is 1920 px. 26% of 1920 should be 499.2 px. The value of 474 is quite far away from the expect 499.

Is my getHeight method not accurate, or the way I set up layout_weight?

Thank you for your time

Comment: What's the actual height of the parent `LinearLayout`? Are you accounting for the status bar?

Comment: Ahhh thank you Mike for pointing out. Turns out that the Nexus emulator I tested on contains the virtual home page, back button, at the bottom of the screen that is taking up space! And I did not account for them. Problem solved :)

Comment: Ah, yeah, that would make more sense. From the figures you gave, it's about 96 off for the total height, which would more likely be the navigation bar, than the status bar. Well, glad you got it figured out. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

You can use PercentRelativeLayout

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.3.0'
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

Hope! Help You!

Comment: Thanks! I didnt know PercentRelativeLayout exists. Will definitely look into it!